# App assigned to one desktop stays behind apps assigned to all desktops

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control

In macOS 14.0 "Sonoma" [EDIT: now also on 14.1], the following buggy behavior keeps returning at random times.

Situation:

- I have assigned certain apps to a single Desktop (that is, to one of the Spaces I have set up): when I open **app A**, its window will always be opened on Desktop 1; **app B** on Desktop 2.
- I have also assigned a few apps (let's say **apps C and D**) to *All desktops*: their windows will be visible on each of the Spaces.
- My settings: Stage Manager is off; for Mission Control the only setting that's not off is "Displays have separate Spaces" (but I'm using only the built-in display anyway).

Problem:

- From time to time, one of the Spaces gets corrupted in the following way: on that Desktop, the app assigned to it *permanently stays behind the All-desktop apps*, and it's impossible to bring it forward (other than by minimizing or closing the All-desktop windows). So for example, when Desktop 2 has this problem, when I <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to app B, the view switches to Desktop 2, but there I can see app B only behind app C and app D, and even clicking on app B does not bring it to the front.
- Nothing seems to solve this - not even a restart. I end up creating a new Space, dragging app B to it and assigning it to that desktop, dragging the desktop to location 2, and dragging the old Desktop 2 away to last place (or closing it).

I have not had this problem in earlier macOS versions and can't find information on it. What's going on, has this occurred with others, and what is the remedy?

Comment: First thing to do with any early version of the OS is update to the latest version & see if they fixed it. 14.1 is current.

Comment: @Tetsujin OK, I just updated to 14.1. Literally the first thing that happened was that app A, on Desktop 1, dropped behind apps C and D. There we go again...